# convert from array of cells to a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a msg of size 1227
each cell inside it has a row of data. each row with different size 
I want to create a matrix with 1227 rows 
each row from a different cell

how can I do that ?

Comment: In a matrix, by definition, all rows have the same length. You would have to fill with values; is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

In a matrix, by definition, all rows have the same length. You have to fill with values, such as `NaN`:

```
data = {1:3, 4:5, 6:9}; %// example data
M = numel(data); %// number of rows
N = max(cellfun(@numel, data)); %// maximum number of columns
matrix = NaN(M, N); %// initiallize with NaN (used as fill value)
for m = 1:M
    row = data{m}; %// extract values of cell
    matrix(m, 1:numel(row)) = row; %// write to first entries of matrix row
end
```

In this example,

```
>> celldisp(data)
data{1} =
     1     2     3
data{2} =
     4     5
data{3} =
     6     7     8     9

>> matrix
matrix =
     1     2     3   NaN
     4     5   NaN   NaN
     6     7     8     9
```